# How to create a data readable by R given raw data of dates and daily rainfall(in mm)?

Tags: r

I have dates ranging from 1970 to 1990 with observations of daily rainfall (in mm) in that period. How do I write/convert these data into something like "data(rain)" so that I can carry out further statistical calculations?
the dates are also a major problem. I would like to use the daily rainfall as y axis and dates as x axis.

I can do it the long way with rainfall in this manner:
rainfall<-c(20,23,25,30,38,24....) which is too long considering i have a lot of observations,
but how do i write the x axis of daily dates?

Please help??

Comment: What type of file is the data in now? Start here for an explanation of how to import data into R (http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-data.pdf‎). Your second question is largely a matter of reading `?as.Date` and `?strptime`. Once you've imported your data and converted the dates to dates recognized by R is becomes a simple matter of just calling `plot`. FYI: `data()` requires package authoring, I'm not sure you're there yet - there are easier ways to import data.

Comment: in my excel sheet, there is dates in column A and rainfall in column B

Comment: e.g January 13, 2001 40

Comment: There are numerous ways to read in Excel files. What have you tried?

Comment: df = read.table("clipboard")  is the easiest method i can think of. but i tried and it says "Warning message:
In read.table("clipboard") :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'clipboard'"

Comment: @ben, So was any data read in using that method? What you've identified is a warning, not an error....

Comment: Can you upload your Excel file somewhere (Dropbox??) and post a link to it here?